# Make changes to source files of modules that are imported indirectly and reload them

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

in file1.py, I import module1. In module1, I import module2.
In file1.py, I make changes to module2. How can I ensure those changes are implemented when i call module2 functions in file1.

module1.py

```
a = 0
def func1():
  return a
```

module2.py

```
import module1

def func2():
  return module1.func1()
```

file1.py

```
import module2

def main(x, y):
   f1 = open('module1.py','r')
   data = f1.read()
   data = data.replace(x, y)
   f1.close()
   f2 = open('module1.py','w')
   f2.write(data)
   f2.close()
   print(module2.func2())

main("a = 0", "a = 2")
importlib.reload(module2)
main("a = 2", "a = 4")
```

I tried using importlib.reload(), but the changes are not made.

I want it to print 2 and 4.

Comment: That's a very strange thing to do and I wouldn't spend effort to make it work, but rather find a better solution for what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Why do you reload module2 when you are changing the file module1.py?

Comment: but module1 is not imported in file1.py. so you cannot reload it

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: NVM, it works now. I had to call importlib within main

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.